# Cannot use `gcloud auth print-identity-token` from within Vertex AI Custom Job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, service-accounts, google-cloud-vertex-ai

#### Background

- I want to use a service account, with a vertex AI custom job, and create an identity token.
- I am attempting to notify a cloud run API once a vertex-AI custom job has finished.
- I have created a service account with a `roles/run.invoker` role, and have confirmed that the service account can access the cloud run API.

  - I used credentials from the service account and created an identity token with audience set to the cloud run API URL

#### Problem

- When a vertex AI custom job is created using [`gcloud ai custom-jobs create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai/custom-jobs/create) or through the [golang client library](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/aiplatform), an identity token cannot be obtained for a custom service account.

  - `gcloud auth print-identity-token` results in an error:

    - `(gcloud.auth.print-identity-token) No identity token can be obtained from the current credentials.`
  - Using the [metadata server URL](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#use_the_metadata_server) directly gives a `Not Found` response.

    - Command:

      ```
      curl \
        -s \
        --get \
        --data-urlencode "audience=$CLOUD_RUN_API_URL" \
        --data-urlencode "format=full" \
        -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" \
        http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity
      ```
    - Response: `Not Found`
- I need some guidance on what settings / way of invoking the custom job will allow me to access the service account's identity token.

---

#### Details

- For the purposes of testing creating an identity token, the custom container is specified using the docker file below:

```
FROM alpine:3.6

RUN apk add --update python curl which bash
RUN curl -sSL https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash -s -- --disable-prompts
ENV PATH $PATH:/root/google-cloud-sdk/bin

CMD ["gcloud", "auth", "print-identity-token", "--verbosity", "debug"]
```

- The following produce a working identity token:

  - ✅ Running this image locally
  - ✅ Running this image using the "Create" button on the vertex AI GUI and setting the service account to my custom one, created for this use case.
  - ✅ Running this image using `gcloud` with NO service account set (using vertex-ai default service account for the project)
- The following results in an error (the problem which prompted me to ask this question):

  - ❌ Running this image using `gcloud` with the following settings, I get an **error**:

    - Command (image name/service account redacted):

      ```
      gcloud ai custom-jobs create \
        --region=asia-northeast1 \
        --display-name=cli_identity_test \
        --worker-pool-spec=machine-type=n2-standard-4,replica-count=1,container-image-uri=<IMAGE NAME> \
        --service-account=<SERVICE ACCOUNT EMAIL>
      ```
    - Error:

      ```
      DEBUG: (gcloud.auth.print-identity-token) No identity token can be obtained from the current credentials.                                                                
      Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                       
        File "/root/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 987, in Execute                                                                                 
          resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)                                                                                                                
        File "/root/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 809, in Run                                                                                 
          resources = command_instance.Run(args)                                                                                                                               
        File "/root/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/exceptions.py", line 129, in TryFunc                                                                          
          return func(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                         
        File "/root/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/auth/print_identity_token.py", line 130, in Run                                                                               
          credential = _Run(args)                                                                                                                                              
        File "/root/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/auth/print_identity_token.py", line 78, in _Run                                                                               
          'No identity token can be obtained from the current credentials.')                                                                                                   
      InvalidIdentityTokenError: No identity token can be obtained from the current credentials.                                                                               
      ERROR: (gcloud.auth.print-identity-token) No identity token can be obtained from the current credentials.
      ```
  - ❌ Running the image with a custom service account, and using the vertex ai golang API client library to start the job

---

#### A note on roles

- I have also tried extending the roles associated with my service account, but these do not fix the error:

  - to match the default vertex-ai service account (`roles/aiplatform.customCodeServiceAgent`)
  - Service Account Token Creator (`roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator`)
  - Service Account User (`roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`)

Comment: I wrote that: https://medium.com/google-cloud/service-account-credentials-api-a-solution-to-different-issues-dc7434037115 I'm sure you can reuse that API with an Access Token to generate and identity token. I had a similar issue with Cloud Build at a time (I think it's fixed now).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [that](https://medium.com/google-cloud/service-account-credentials-api-a-solution-to-different-issues-dc7434037115)

I'm sure you can reuse that API with an Access Token to generate and identity token. I had a similar issue with Cloud Build at a time (I think it's fixed now).

Comment: I managed to get an identity key using `gcloud auth print-access-token` in combination with https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest. If you add more details regarding that to this answer, I'm happy to accept

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import google.auth.transport.requests
import google.oauth2.id_token
auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, <AUDIENCE>)
```

Example: Audience for cloud function will look like
`https://<REGION>-<PROJECT_ID>.cloudfunctions.net/<FUNCTION_NAME>`